# How can i get my code to test just one line in a text file?

Tags: python, authentication, system

Hello i am looking for some help. so for some back ground this code is going to be used as a log in system for personal use. i am trying to get it to check just one line so i can get it to validate that the username is correct and or the password. how would i do this?

```
user = input("please Enter your full name: ")
if os.path.isfile(user + ".txt"):
    with open(user + ".txt", "r")

        print("------------------------")
        Username = input("|Username: ")
        password = getpass.getpass("|Password: ")
        print("------------------------")
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if you insist on doing it in an insecure way then I guess you have just a file with a plaintext user name and password in it. I understand that perhaps you are knew to Python so an insecure method is somewhat acceptable :P. Example below,

bosh

password

(in the file there would be no gap between lines as shown above, they would be on consecutive lines)

If not then I recommend you do this as this is how the code section below will expect it to be.

```
submittedUsername = input("Please enter username: ")
submittedPassword = input("Please enter password: ")
credentialsFile = open("credentials.txt", "r")
credentials = credentialsFile.readlines()
username = credentials[0].rstrip("\n\r")
password = credentials[1].rstrip("\n\r")
if submittedUsername == username:
    if submittedPassword == password:
        print("Login verified!")
        #both username and password verified here, do what you want
    else:
        #password incorrect
        print("Login invalid")
else:
    #username incorrect but whether you want to specify what is wrong is up to you
    print("Login invalid")
```

If there are any parts you would like explaining, do ask. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. i understand that this is insecure, can you link me to anywhere which will explain how i can make a more secure version where credentials are hidden etc.

Comment: My pleasure. Yes, I'm afraid it is but it's great to hear you'd like to improve it. If you want to, I'd look into hashing the password using SHA-512 with hashlib. You might want to start by looking here http://pythoncentral.io/hashing-strings-with-python/ I would say to look at SHA 512 as quite a few of the others are no longer considered secure. Good luck. :) P.S, please upvote the answer and mark it as accepted.